# Zsh keybind to CTRL+equals

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I would like to bind a zsh function to the key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>. I haven't found any working way to do this. If it is possible, I would like to know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> keybind is not distinguished from the plain <kbd>=</kbd> key. While you could bind it, you would also bind to any regular press of equals.

Binding a function to a key is quite easy. You just need to turn the function into a ZSH Widget first. For example:

```
% function hello_function { echo "hello" }
% zle -N hello_widget hello_function
% bindkey '=' hello_widget
```

You can find the string to put into bindkey by typing ctrl-v and then your desired keystroke. So I can see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> can be represented as `'^E'` by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Not all modifiers result in a different bindable key, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It it too bad that it isn't possible to set arbitrary keybindings :(

Comment: There are probably more bindable keys than you think. The control-v trick is quite nifty, but if the key already has a binding then it can interfere with it. You can certainly bind the function keys, and every letter I have tried worked. Maybe try to think of a new nemonic for the action you are trying to perform.